# How to Upload and Display the Files in Frontend in Linux Cpanel Hosting?

Tags: hosting, cpanel

Friends i had purchased a Linux with Cpanel hosting to upload my Site.

But if i have entered the ip Address i cant get the Index OF Directory. .

I got the Error File Not Found. .

Cant able to display the Uploaded Files in frontend. .

Also cant able to change the local Apache Default Index To Public_html.

Pls Help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you please give a try with "Index Manager" option in Cpanel and select "No indexing" and check this again.